# evm error: revert

Tags: revert

This is my first smart contract. I booked a ticket and cancelled it in remix ide connected to metamask. Everything worked fine in remix ide. But my cancelling ticket test failed in foundry.

## Test output:[image]

## Here is my test code

[image]

## Main contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract FlightBooking {
address payable public contractOwner;

```
uint256 public totalSeats;
uint256 public bookedSeats;
uint256 public constant ticketPrice = 1 ether;

struct Ticket {
    string PassengerName;
    uint256 SeatNumber;
    bool exists;
}

mapping(address => mapping(uint => Ticket)) public tickets;
mapping(address => uint) public userTicketCount;
mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
mapping(uint => bool) public isSeatBooked;

constructor(uint256 _totalSeats) {
    contractOwner = payable(msg.sender);
    totalSeats = _totalSeats;
    bookedSeats = 0;
}

function bookFlightTicket(
    string memory passengerName,
    uint seatNumber
) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= ticketPrice, "Insufficient funds");
    require(
        seatNumber > 0 && seatNumber <= totalSeats,
        "Invalid seat number"
    );
    require(!isSeatBooked[seatNumber], "seat already booked");

    balances[msg.sender] += ticketPrice;
    bookedSeats++;

    uint ticketId = userTicketCount[msg.sender];
    tickets[msg.sender][ticketId] = Ticket(passengerName, seatNumber, true);
    userTicketCount[msg.sender]++;
    isSeatBooked[seatNumber] = true;
}

function cancelFlightTicket(uint ticketId) public payable {
    require(userTicketCount[msg.sender] > 0, "No ticket to cancel");
    require(ticketId < userTicketCount[msg.sender], "Invalid ticketId");

    // Ticket storage ticket = tickets[msg.sender][ticketId];
    require(
        tickets[msg.sender][ticketId].exists == true,
        "ticket does not exist"
    );

    balances[msg.sender] -= ticketPrice;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(ticketPrice);
    bookedSeats--;

    isSeatBooked[tickets[msg.sender][ticketId].SeatNumber] = false;
    delete tickets[msg.sender][ticketId];
    userTicketCount[msg.sender]--;
}

function getOwnerBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return contractOwner.balance;
}
```

}